# Recuperar valores da Partial View para View Pai

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, partialview

Estou desenvolvendo uma tela em AspNet Mvc onde eu tenho um tela index que tem uma model chamada ParametrizacaoVM e nessa tela tenho um partialView que exibe as unidades (que é uma `List<Unidades>` que esta contido na model parametrizacaoVM)

Chamada da ParialView:

```
  @Html.Partial("GridMvc", Model.ListaUnidades)
```

quando do um submit no formulário pai(Index) as informações referente a lista de unidades não chega na controller, fica como nullo e quando tentei colocar o atributo `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListaUnidades)` na index, na controller a lista chega zerada.

Alguem sabe como resolver esse problema, para que quando realizar um submit no formulario ele considere a lista que esta na partialview?

Index:

```
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm(@acao, "Parametrizacao", @ajaxOptions, new { @id = "FormCadastroParametrizacao" }))
        {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IdCliente)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RazaoSocialOperadora)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SiglaContrato)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CodigoContrato)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Cadastrar)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListaUnidades)
        <form>

         //Outros campos dessa tela....

          @Html.Partial("GridMvc", Model.ListaUnidades)

            <input type="submit" id="btnSalvar" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-salvar" />

    </form>
}
```

PartialView

```
    @model IEnumerable<Fleury.NovoVAEL.Entidades.Model.Unidade>
@using GridMvc.Html


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GridMvc";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/ScriptsParametrizacao/PaginacaoGridMvc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/gridmvc-ext.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/GridCustomizada.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="results">

    <b>Selecione as Unidades</b><div class="code-cut">

        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(Columns =>
   {
       Columns.Add(c => c.Selecionado)
                .Encoded(false)
                .Sanitized(false)
                .Filterable(true)
                .SetWidth(30)
                .RenderValueAs(o => Html.CheckBox(o.Codigo.ToString(), o.Selecionado));
       Columns.Add(c => c.IdUnidadeSAP).Titled("ID Unidade SAP").Filterable(true);
       Columns.Add(c => c.Codigo).Titled("ID Unidade Legado").Filterable(true);
       Columns.Add(c => c.Descricao).Titled("Desc. Unidade").Filterable(true);
       Columns.Add(c => c.CodPrestadorSAP).Titled("Cod. Prestador SAP").Filterable(true);
       Columns.Add(c => c.CodPrestadorVAEL)
       .Titled("Cod. Prestador VAEL")
       .Filterable(true)
       .Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false)
       .SetWidth(30)
       .RenderValueAs(c => Html.TextBox(c.Codigo.ToString(), c.CodPrestadorVAEL, new { @class = "form-control" }));

   }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true).WithMultipleFilters()



    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Pode colocar código da view completa junto com a partial view e o controller

Comment: @NetinhoSantos adicionei o codigo da partial

Comment: Remove esse <form> logo depois do @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListaUnidades)

Comment: Removi mas continuo com o mesmo problema